# Will GCM be deprecated and FCM will take place of it?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is firebase taking GCM place or what extra is firebase doing so that we can relay on FCM rather than GCM.

If we use GCM in our new messaging app shall we have to completely migrate to FCM in near future ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q. Why is Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) part of Firebase?
   How does it relate to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)?

A. Google is investing in Firebase, making it our unified mobile platform.

Over the last few years, we have expanded GCM to send messages to multiple platforms beyond Android: iOS and Chrome. Firebase is known for being cross platform, so FCM now makes a natural fit in the Firebase suite of features designed for Android, iOS, and mobile web.

Another core value of Firebase is cross-feature integration. We are adding the ability for other Firebase features to easily send messages via FCM. For example, you can use Firebase Notifications to send reengagement messages to your users.

We think that GCM will be even more useful to developers as an integrated part of Firebase. You can still get the same great product, now under a new name: "Firebase Cloud Messaging," or FCM for short.

Q. How different is GCM from FCM? What is new in FCM SDKs?

A. FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits GCM’s core infrastructure to make sure we continue to deliver messages reliably on Android, iOS and Chrome.

The new FCM SDK:

Simplifies client development. You no longer have to write your own registration or subscription retry logic.
Enables a new serverless notifications solution with a web console, Firebase Notifications. With Firebase Notifications, anyone can send notifications to target specific audiences based on Firebase Analytics insights. They can then evaluate notification effectiveness by assessing the built-in Notifications Funnel Analysis in the console.
FCM Android and iOS SDKs make messaging and notifications development easier. They offer an out-of-the-box solution so that anyone can send notifications from Firebase Notifications immediately.

Q. Is GCM going to be deprecated?

A. We will continue to support the current version of GCM Android and iOS SDKs because we know a lot of developers are using GCM SDKs today to handle notifications, and client app upgrade takes time.

But all new client-side features will be added to FCM SDKs only moving forward. You are strongly encouraged to upgrade to FCM SDKs.

For More Check This: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq

Answer (score 0):

Google is now encouraging using FCM. Here it shows a message if you go to GCM doc.

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See the FAQ to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.

In future they may not update their apis as they are now focusing on FCM.

So, From my opinion if you start new then use FCM. It's nice & easy to configure & implement.